# Closed workbook remains in VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010.
When I close a workbook through the UI, or even through the `workbooks(name_of_workbook).close` method, the workbook remains in the VBA editor as a project.

Why is this? Is there a way to remove closed workbooks from the VBA editor?

Comment: Is your workbook an addin? Is it referred (using references) by any other open workbooks in VBA?

Comment: No, it's just a standard workbook. However, I have encountered a similar situation with workbooks that refer to another open workbook through VBA references.

Comment: Please check references of the other open workbooks. It could be a case where an existing open workbook (or addin) is referring to this workbook.

Comment: I am positive there are no references in these workbooks to other workbooks through VBA.

Comment: Similar thread... closing a workbook, then reopening the same workbook produces *2* listings in the VBA project listings; even though they are the same file.

Comment: I think I may have an answer. I have two VBA add-ins open as well, the Smart Indenter and VBA MZ-Tools. I tried opening and closing a workbook on a machine where these are not loaded (both add-ins require some registry tweaking to load properly on our machines) and I didn't encounter the issue.

Comment: @Harry post your comment as an answer and mark it as the answer, so others can benefit, even if you answered it yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have an answer. I have two VBA add-ins open as well, the Smart Indenter and VBA MZ-Tools. I tried opening and closing a workbook on a machine where these are not loaded (both add-ins require some registry tweaking to load properly on our machines) and I didn't encounter the issue.

Comment: See also my answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696636/excel-vba-project-not-getting-closed/25744783#25744783

Comment: I have the exact same issue with pure VBA (not COM-Add-In, C#, VSTO, ...) in Excel365 (V2201 - 16.0.14827.20158, 64bit), but no add-ins are active. What can I try?