# Closed excel workbooks remain in VBA IDE

Tags: excel, vba, ide

## Summary

My dead simple Excel workbook *myTestBook.xlsb* has a single empty table and a single code module with the routine `test_openclose()` inside. This routine just opens another Excel workbook (*Mappe3.xlsx*), then closes that workbook again.
When the routine is run (*Alt-F8*) with the VBA IDE closed, **everything is fine**.
When the routine is run (*Alt-F8*) with the VBA IDE opened, the **intermittently opened workbooks keep getting listed** in the IDE's project explorer. Each repetitive run leads to another entry in the IDE's project explorer.
**Why is that and what can I do against this effect?**

View after 6 runs with closed IDE (no entries) and 3 runs with IDE open (3 entries):
[image]

You can also see that the Workbook *Mappe3.xlsx* which is getting imported, is very simple too: just a single (empty) table, no named ranges, no internal or external references, no modules.

## Code

I am using
° MS Windows 10 Pro x64, 10.0.19042
° Excel365 (V2201 - 16.0.14827.20158, 64bit)
° Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1, Retail 7.1.1119, Forms3: 16.0.14827.20024

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_openclose()
    Dim srcBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim name As String
    
    name = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Mappe3.xlsx"
    
    ' Open a workbook:
    Set srcBook = Workbooks.Open(filename:=name)
    
    ' Do something useful,
    ' e.g. enter the current time:
    srcBook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = Str(Now)
    
    ' Close the workbook and destroy the object
    Workbooks(srcBook.name).Close savechanges:=False
    Set srcBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

## What I have tried

I have checked that no "exotic" references are ticked:
[image]

I have also checked that no "exotic" add-ins are active:
[image]
[image]

I have checked for similar questions and answers, but the suggested solutions do not apply to my case:

- I have already coded like [`set wb=nothing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722362/vba-project-explorer-still-showing-the-excel-workbooks-which-are-closed-by-the-m?rq=1), but to no avail
- I do not use [shared workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740482/why-do-files-remain-in-project-window-even-after-files-closed)
- I am on pure VBA, [not COM-Add-In, C#, VSTO, ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696636/excel-vba-project-not-getting-closed/25744783#25744783)
- There are no [add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605164/closed-workbook-remains-in-vba-editor/8760306#comment125831016_8760306)

**What else can I try?**

Comment: I have noticed the same problem, but also have noted it only relatively recently.  May be a version issue (I am using O365 v2102)? I have not found a fix, but equally it has not caused problems - other than being annoying.

Comment: Try  `srcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False` and get rid of the line `Set srcBook = Nothing`. VBA's garbage collector deals with it, maybe you're confusing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect does not show when the workbook is closed differently:
with the code

```
    ' Close the workbook
    srcBook.Close savechanges:=False
```

instead of

```
    ' Close the workbook and destroy the object
    Workbooks(srcBook.name).Close savechanges:=False
    Set srcBook = Nothing
```

the effect is not observed.

Thankyou [VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008) for the above comment!